# Oracle SQL format mask to_number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in which I could have negative values in 2 different formats: trailing sign normal minus sign. So far, I've tried the below but one of them fails for each number. Is there a way I could cover all my scenarios?

```
SELECT
    str,
    to_number(str, 'fm999.99mi') AS opt1,
    to_number(str, 'fm999.99') AS opt2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            '-92.93' AS str
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            '92.93-' AS str1
        FROM
            dual
    );
```

My desired output would be:

| str | opt1 | opt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -92.93 | -92.93 | -92.93 |
| -92.93 | -92.93 | -92.93 |

EDIT: version Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a case expression to modify the format mask:

```
to_number(str, 'fm999.99' || case when substr(str, -1) = '-' then 'mi' end)
```

With your data:

```
SELECT
    str,
    to_number(str, 'fm999.99' || case when substr(str, -1) = '-' then 'mi' end) AS num
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            '-92.93' AS str
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            '92.93-' AS str1
        FROM
            dual
    );
```

gets

```
STR         NUM
-------- ------
-92.93   -92.93
92.93-   -92.93
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b34222edc810b12cf14c2be68005a161)

I don't think the `fm` is really adding anything here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string functions to check if the minus sign is at the end of the string and reverse it:

```sql
SELECT str,
       TO_NUMBER(
         CASE
         WHEN str LIKE '%-'
         THEN '-' || SUBSTR( str, 1, LENGTH(str) - 1 )
         ELSE str
         END,
         'fm999.99'
       ) AS num
FROM   (
  SELECT '-92.93' AS str FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '92.93-' AS str FROM DUAL
);
```

Which outputs:

> | STR | NUM |
> | --- | --- |
> | -92.93 | -92.93 |
> | 92.93- | -92.93 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af02bd7236b328155c85e07d125165fc)*

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `on conversion error` and `coalesce()`.  That is, return `NULL` instead of an error and choose the first non-`NULL` value.

For your example:

```
SELECT str,
       coalesce(to_number(str default null on conversion error, 'fm999.99mi'),
                to_number(str, 'fm999.99')
               ) AS opt
```

In earlier versions, you would use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT str,
       (CASE WHEN str LIKE '%-'
             THEN to_number(str, 'fm999.99mi')
             ELSE to_number(str, 'fm999.99')
        END) AS opt
```

Comment: It says missing right parenthesis but cannot work out which one it is as all seem fine to me.

Comment: @jeiv - you'd get that if you're on a version of Oracle older than 12cR2, which introduced `on conversion error`.

Comment: What would be the alternative for lower versions? :(